# Program compiled with assimp will not start

Tags: c++, visual-studio, assimp

I have recently updated my game engine source code to use the visual studio(2017) vc141 toolkit.

I am using Assimp 3.1.1 for model loading. The project compiles and links, and the appropriate dll's are in the debug folder for the solution.

To begin with I was getting a missing dll error "assimp-vc140-mt.dll", which disappeared, when I redownloaded the library, and replaced the dlls/libs/includes, in my solution.

But now, when I try to run the program I get:

```
"The application was unable to start correctly (0x000007b). Click OK to close the application."
```

I've never seen this error before. Could this be related to the new toolkit?

Comment: Visual Studio has one of the, if not the, best debuggers in the business, so I suggest that you use it: run your program under the debugger and it when it crashes it should halt on the actual line of code that caused the crash.  Because 99% of the time, the problem is actually going to be in your own code, not in the toolkit, not in the libraries, not anywhere else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to recompile assimp from source, which gave me the proper files I needed.